# Deploy rocket chat with docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, rocket.chat

It seems that rocket is connected to mongo, but it keeps loading when opening the website, so there is something wrong with my configuration.

I use the officially recommended docker configuration

The website is at this location

https://docs.rocket.chat/deploy/deploy-rocket.chat/deploy-with-docker-and-docker-compose
First of all, I was confused when I first saw it. His description seemed to be that I only need to modify MONGO_URL and ROOT_URL. The problem lies in this MONGO_URL. I thought that user and pass were filled in casually, and then the env help would be automatically passed. I went to generate it in mongo, but I soon discovered that the rocket could not be connected. I found the reason for this was the host, because I asked Bing chat, and then after connecting, it prompted that the authentication information failed, and then I tried again. After searching many ways, I entered the mongo container and finally created a user and password. The final status was that it didn't seem to report an error, and then it kept loading when I opened the website.

```bash
[root@tom chat]# tree -a .
.
├── compose.yml
└── .env

0 directories, 2 files
[root@tom chat]# 
[root@tom chat]# cat compose.yml 
volumes:
  mongodb_data: { driver: local }

services:
  rocketchat:
    image: registry.rocket.chat/rocketchat/rocket.chat:${RELEASE:-latest}
    restart: always
    labels:
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.rocketchat.rule: Host(`${DOMAIN:-}`)
      traefik.http.routers.rocketchat.tls: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.rocketchat.entrypoints: https
      traefik.http.routers.rocketchat.tls.certresolver: le
    environment:
      MONGO_URL: "${MONGO_URL:-\
        mongodb://${MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME:-mongodb}:${MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_PORT_NUMBER:-27017}/\
        ${MONGODB_DATABASE:-rocketchat}?replicaSet=${MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME:-rs0}}"
      MONGO_OPLOG_URL: "${MONGO_OPLOG_URL:\
        -mongodb://${MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME:-mongodb}:${MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_PORT_NUMBER:-27017}/\
        local?replicaSet=${MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME:-rs0}}"
      ROOT_URL: ${ROOT_URL:-http://localhost:${HOST_PORT:-3000}}
      PORT: ${PORT:-3000}
      DEPLOY_METHOD: docker
      DEPLOY_PLATFORM: ${DEPLOY_PLATFORM:-}
      REG_TOKEN: ${REG_TOKEN:-}
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    expose:
      - ${PORT:-3000}
    ports:
      - "${BIND_IP:-0.0.0.0}:${HOST_PORT:-3000}:${PORT:-3000}"

  mongodb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:${MONGODB_VERSION:-5.0}
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/bitnami/mongodb
    environment:
      MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE: primary
      MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME: ${MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME:-rs0}
      MONGODB_PORT_NUMBER: ${MONGODB_PORT_NUMBER:-27017}
      MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_HOST: ${MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_HOST:-mongodb}
      MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_PORT_NUMBER: ${MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_PORT_NUMBER:-27017}
      MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME: ${MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME:-mongodb}
      MONGODB_ENABLE_JOURNAL: ${MONGODB_ENABLE_JOURNAL:-true}
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: ${ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD:-yes}
[root@tom chat]#
```

```bash
[root@tom chat]# cat .env 
### Rocket.Chat configuration

# Rocket.Chat version
# see:- https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/releases
#RELEASE=
# MongoDB endpoint (include ?replicaSet= parameter)
MONGO_URL=mongodb://rocketchat:admin123@mongodb:27017/rocketchat?authSource=admin
ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
# MongoDB endpoint to the local database
#MONGO_OPLOG_URL=
# IP to bind the process to
#BIND_IP=
# URL used to access your Rocket.Chat instance
ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
# Port Rocket.Chat runs on (in-container)
#PORT=
# Port on the host to bind to
#HOST_PORT=

### MongoDB configuration
# MongoDB version/image tag
#MONGODB_VERSION=
# See:- https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mongodb

### Traefik config (if enabled)
# Traefik version/image tag
#TRAEFIK_RELEASE=
# Domain for https (change ROOT_URL & BIND_IP accordingly)
#DOMAIN=
# Email for certificate notifications
#LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=
[root@tom chat]#
```

```bash
[root@mx ~]# docker exec -it MongoDB bash
root@mongodatabase:/# 

root@mongodatabase:/# mongo

mongodatabase:SECONDARY> rs.initiate()
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "already initialized",
        "code" : 23,
        "codeName" : "AlreadyInitialized",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1635072585, 2),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1635072585, 2)
}

mongodatabase:PRIMARY> use admin
switched to db admin
mongodatabase:PRIMARY> 

db.createUser({user: "root",pwd: "admin123",roles: [{ role: "root", db: "admin"}]})
db.createUser({user: "rocketchat",pwd: "admin123",roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "local" }]})

use rocketchat
db.createUser({user: "rocketchat",pwd: "admin123",roles: [{role: "dbOwner",db: "rocketchat" }]})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPBze.png)